# Integrating Youtube API in Android app

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, playlist

I managed to play a youtube video in Android, but i cant understand how to create a playlist.
There is a code in the documentation:

```
POST {base_URL}/playlists?part=snippet
 Request body:
{
'snippet': {
  'title': 'New playlist', 
  'description': 'Sample playlist for Data API',
 }
}
```

But I don't know how to implement it my app. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Playlists: insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert) to create a playlist.

HTTP request
`POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists`

You may check the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert#examples) wherein the sample calls the API's `playlists.insert` method to create a private playlist owned by the channel authorizing the request.

```
//Create a new, private playlist in the authorized user's channel.
String playlistId = insertPlaylist();
```

You may also check on this [tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-youtube-api-example-channels/).

Hope this helps!